# Как вытащить значение из словаря JSON?

Tags: python, json

Пишу на Python. Из словаря в JSON нужно вытащить значение ключа "city". Кусок словаря ниже.

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2018-07-15T13:21:02Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
      "channel": {
        "units": {
          "distance": "mi",
          "pressure": "in",
          "speed": "mph",
          "temperature": "F"
        },
        "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Nome, AK, US",
        "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
        "description": "Yahoo! Weather for Nome, AK, US",
        "language": "en-us",
        "lastBuildDate": "Sun, 15 Jul 2018 05:21 AM AKDT",
        "ttl": "60",
        "location": {
          "city": "Nome",
          "country": "United States",
          "region": " AK"
        },
        "wind": {
          "chill": "50",
          "direction": "270",
          "speed": "11"
        },
        "atmosphere": {
          "humidity": "90",
          "pressure": "1009.0",
          "rising": "0",
          "visibility": "14.9"
        },
        "astronomy": {
          "sunrise": "1:4 am",
          "sunset": "5:9 am"
        },
        "image": {
          "title": "Yahoo! Weather",
          "width": "142",
          "height": "18",
          "link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
          "url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
        },
        "item": {
          "title": "Conditions for Nome, AK, US at 03:00 AM AKDT",
          "lat": "64.499474",
          "long": "-165.405792",
          "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
          "pubDate": "Sun, 15 Jul 2018 03:00 AM AKDT",
          "condition": {
            "code": "26",
            "date": "Sun, 15 Jul 2018 03:00 AM AKDT",
            "temp": "52",
            "text": "Cloudy"
          },
          "forecast": [
            {
              "code": "11",
              "date": "15 Jul 2018",
              "day": "Sun",
              "high": "53",
              "low": "49",
              "text": "Showers"
            },
```

Значение ключа "count" вывести получается:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response["query"]["count"])
```

А вот то, что дальше не знаю как оформить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы можете исправить JSON? Он у вас оборван на середине... [Чтобы проверить JSON ...](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Добавила еще информации, сам словарь очень длинный, мне скорее он нужен для примера, чтобы понять как в данном случае оформить синтаксис.

Comment: Лучше длинный, чем [сломанный](https://jsonlint.com/) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
In [193]: import dpath    #  pip install dpath

In [194]: dpath.util.search(response, '**/city')
Out[194]: {'query': {'results': {'channel': {'location': {'city': 'Nome'}}}}}

In [199]: dpath.util.values(response, '**/city')
Out[199]: ['Nome']

In [200]: dpath.util.get(response, '/query/results/channel/location/city')
Out[200]: 'Nome'
```

PS [пример валидного JSON `response`](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)...

```
In [201]: url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22munich%2C%20germany%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys'

In [202]: import requests

In [203]: response = requests.get(url).json()

In [204]: dpath.util.get(response, '/query/results/channel/location/city')
Out[204]: 'Munich'

In [205]: dpath.util.values(response, '**/city')
Out[205]: ['Munich']

In [206]: dpath.util.search(response, '**/city')
Out[206]: {'query': {'results': {'channel': {'location': {'city': 'Munich'}}}}}

In [207]: dpath.util.get(response, '/query/results/channel/location')
Out[207]: {'city': 'Munich', 'country': 'Germany', 'region': ' BY'}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я не знала какие ключи брать для построения правильной цепочки до значения, попробовала следующее:    print(response["query"]["results"]["channel"]["location"]["city"]) и это сработало